# Return stock symbol in quantopian

Tags: python, list, frameworks, quantmod

I am working on this algo in quantopian and ran into a problem.

I calculated the z-score's for a weighted % price change for a group of etf's and now I am trying to find the ten best stocks. When I run the code

```
print(context.zscore)
```

It gives me data in two columns, the symbol and the zscore. However, when I index this it no longer gives me the symbol, only the zscore

```
print(context.zscore[0])
```

here's a screenshot of the output, the first line is indexed and the second through nth line are not. 
[image]

I want it to return

```
Equity(14516 [EWA])     -.679217
```

or even better

```
EWA      -.679217
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hey! Most likely, the context.zscore object is overriding the __str__ method to put out some custom stuff. I wasn't able to find the reference for zscore by looking very quickly. But, there are probably multiple ways to fix this. 1) Look at the docs, see what that object representation actually is, and if there is a method to get the info you want. 2) Convert the data being printed there to a list.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem it's pretty simple. use [[]]